# mod_rewrite not playing well with cfimport (Coldfusion) on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, coldfusion, apache2, cfimport

Running Apache on OS X Lion and Coldfusion 9 developers edition. I have the following .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

    Options +Indexes
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
```

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.cfm [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.cfm?page=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.cfm?app=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
```

Which is designed to handle URLs like mydomain.com/something and mydomain.com/something/else. Pretty normal stuff.

Everything seems to work fine until I load a file with a cfimport tag in it that looks like this:

```
<cfimport prefix="myLib" taglib="/lib/tags">
```

The RewriteLog shows that this gets picked up and processed and redirected which of course breaks everything.

I've tried adding several conditions like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=lib/tags/ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=lib/tags [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/lib/tags/ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/lib/tags [NC]
```

None of them prevent the problem.

If I restructure the directories so that I load it like this:

```
<cfimport prefix="myLib" taglib="/lib/dir/tags">
```

Everything is fine. This is not an option because this is a group development project and I'm the only one with problems and Windows/IIS is the target deployment environment.

The basic .htaccess file shown at the top appears to work on a co-workers Windows machine running Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why/how cfimport is causing mod_rewrite to fire - it shouldn't even be talking to the web server for that.

Maybe you need to create a `/lib` mapping in CF admin?

Anyway, you can probably stop your rewrite rules fiddling with it by prefixing a negative lookahead onto the start, to tell it to ignore `lib/tags`, like so:

```
(?!lib/tags)
```

Put that after the `^` for the second expression.

Comment: That did it. I agree that the problem makes no sense but you solved it. I'd vote your answer up but I'm too new to the system.